# Global transition/actions in Spring state machine

Tags: spring-statemachine

Is there a way in which I can define global transitions/actions on a Spring state machine?

The expectation is, I'll not be transitioning to any other state. But just accept the event and perform the action and stay in the current state.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that there is no support for global transition. We developed a layer on top of Spring State Machine(SSM), which could be configured with JSON. From that, we had a possibility to define the global transition. And, when translating to SSM objects, the global transition will be added to all the states.